# Order a list with pointers

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm supposed to order the numbers inserted in this list. I have to order it backwards too. I've been trying to do it for the last couple of hours but I haven't come up with anything. I'm a beginner and to me the hardest part is to order it using of its pointers.

```
    public class MyList {

    private static class MyList
    {
        public int num;
        public MyList nextn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        MyList start = null;
        MyList end = null;
        MyList aux;
        MyList before;
        int op, number, found;
        do{
            System.out.println("1- insert number in the beginning list");
            System.out.println("2- insert in the end of the list");
            System.out.println("3- query list");
            System.out.println("4- remove from list");
            System.out.println("5- empty list");
            System.out.println("6- exit");
            System.out.print("choose: ");
            op = input.nextInt();
            if(op < 1||op>6)
            {
                System.out.println("invalid number");
            }
            if(op == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("type the number to be inserted in the beginning of the list");
                MyList newl = new MyList();
                newl.num = input.nextInt();
                if(start == null)
                {
                    start = newl;
                    end = newl;
                    newl.nextn = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    newl.nextn = start;
                    start = newl;
                }
                System.out.println("number inserted");
            }
            if(op == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("type the number to be inserted in the end of the list");
                MyList newl = new MyList();
                newl.num = input.nextInt();
                if(start == null)
                {
                    start = newl;
                    end = newl;
                    newl.nextn = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    end.nextn = newl;
                    end = newl;
                    newl.nextn = null;
                }
                System.out.println("number inserted");
            }
            if(op == 3)
            {
                if(start == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("list is empty");
                }
                else
                {  System.out.println("\nquerying the list\n");
                    aux = start;
                    while(aux!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.print(aux.num+ " ");
                        aux = aux.nextn;

                    }
                }
            }
            if(op == 4)
            {
                if(start == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("list is empty");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("\ntype the number to be removed:\n");
                    number = input.nextInt();
                    aux = start;
                    before = null;
                    found = 0;

                    while(aux!=null)
                    {
                        if(aux.num == number)
                        {
                            found = found +1;
                            if(aux == start)
                            {
                                start = aux.nextn;
                                aux = start;
                            }
                            else if(aux == end)
                            {
                                before.nextn = null;
                                end = before;
                                aux = null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                before.nextn =aux.nextn;
                                aux = aux.nextn;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            before = aux;
                            aux =aux.nextn;
                        }
                    }
                    if(found ==0)  {
                        System.out.append("number not found");
                    }
                    else if(found ==1)
                    {
                        System.out.append("number removed once!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.append("number removed "+found+" times!");
                    }
                }
            }
            if(op == 5)
            {
                if(start == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("empty list");
                }
                else
                {
                    start = null;
                    System.out.println("emptied list");
                }
            }
        } while(op !=6);
    }
```

Comment: Java doesn't provide you to play with the *pointers* like C/C++. And the biggest problem I find here is that your inner class has the same name as your top class, which makes your code really a mess.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I think the pointer he is referring to is a hypothetical pointer indicating the current value in a sort loop (just a guess).

Comment: @user3816423, are you trying to implement a linked list?  Can you clarify which part of your code you are struggling with?

Comment: @user3816423 what doesn't work exactly? I've compiled it and i think, that it works quite well. Can you provide example input-output that is not correct?

Comment: @MichałSchielmann I'd like to know a way to ORDER this list, increasing and decreasing.

Comment: @user3816423 do you have to do it 'manually', or can you use some Java Api like SortedSet?

Comment: @MichałSchielmann I have to do it manually. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: @user3816423 should it be sorted everytime you insert new value or only when printing the list? If former(first option) then there is no difference in inserting value at the begining from inserting at the end of the list (as everytime the whole list has to be sorted).

Comment: @MichałSchielmann It has to be sorted everytime you insert a new value. Yes I know it doesn't make difference but I tried to keep the original algorithm untouched so that's why it's there

Answer (score 2):

**First - do something with your naming conventions.**

You have two classes with the same name `MyList` (one is `public`, one is `Inner`). That's why I suggest changing the `Inners` class name to `MyListElement`:

```
private class MyListElement
{
    private final Integer value;
    private MyListElement nextElement;

    private MyListElement(final Integer value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

No more `nextn` or `num`. List elements have `values` and `nextElements`. Also - their `values` are `final` (cannot be changed). No more `start`, `op`, `found`, `aux` and so on. Those names mean **** and are not helpful, and are messing up the code.

**Second - don't do everything in a main method.**

It's bad practice. It forces you to use `static` `fields` and `methods`. Create an object in `main` `method` and let that object do the work for you:

```
public class MyList 
{
    private Scanner userInput;
    private Integer selectedOption;

    private MyListElement firstElement = null;
    private boolean exitRequested = false;


    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        MyList myList = new MyList(new Scanner(System.in));
        myList.run();
    }

    private MyList(final Scanner userInput)
    {
        this.userInput = userInput;
    }

    //other methods and classes
}
```

**Third - how should your code work?**

As simple as possible. That said:

```
public void run()
{
    do 
    {
        promptUserForOperation();
        processSelectedOperation();    
    } while(!exitRequested);
}
```

Simple enough?

**Fourth - You know how to prompt. How to process?**

Again - as simple as possible. That said:

```
private void processSelectedOption()
{
    switch (selectedOption)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        {
            addNewElement();
        } break;
        case 3:
        {
            printList();
        } break;
        case 4:
        {
            removeElement();
        } break;
        case 5:
        {
            clearList();
        } break;
        case 6:
        {
            exit();
        } break;
        default:
        {
            printWrongOperationSelected();
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally - how to sort?**

```
private void addNewElement()
{
    //getting the input
    System.out.print("Please type the number to be added to the list: ");

    Integer newValue = null;
    while(newValue == null)
    {
        try
        {
            newValue = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong value. Please insert new value.");
        }
    }

    //creating new element based on the input
    MyListElement newElement = new MyListElement(newValue);

    //if not first
    if (firstElement != null)
    {
        placeElementInList(newElement);
    }
    else
    {
        firstElement = newElement; //if first
    }
}

//if not first
private void placeElementInList(final MyListElement newElement)
{
    //if smaller than first
    if (newElement.value < firstElement.value)
    {
        newElement.nextElement = firstElement;  //new points to first
        firstElement = newElement;              //and becomes first
    }
    else
    {
        MyListElement previousElement = firstElement; //have to remember previous element
        MyListElement elementInList = firstElement.nextElement;  //currently checked.
        while (elementInList != null)
        {
            if (newElement.value < elementInList.value)  //if new element is smaller that currently checked
            {
                break;  //break - put it in current position.
            }
            previousElement = elementInList; //if not, move forward, substitute variables
            elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;
        }
        previousElement.nextElement = newElement;  //set the new element at the proper position
        newElement.nextElement = elementInList;    //
    }
}
```

The remove `method` is almost the same.
And that's all.

You can do it you're way - using the sorting method presented - but I'd suggest learning good habbits as soon as possible. And that is naming your classes/methods/fields/variables properly (they don't have to be short, use ctrl+space), and fragmenting the code to the smallest parts possible. Mind that the above code is far from being perfect - much can be improved.

**SPOILER**

Whole (working) code:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyList 
{
    private Scanner userInput;
    private Integer selectedOption;

    private MyListElement firstElement = null;
    private boolean exitRequested = false;


    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new MyList(new Scanner(System.in)).run();
    }

    private MyList(final Scanner userInput)
    {
        this.userInput = userInput;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        do 
        {
            promptUserForOption();
            processSelectedOption();    
        } while(!exitRequested);
    }

    private void promptUserForOption()
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1 - insert number in the beginning list");
        System.out.println("2 - insert in the end of the list");
        System.out.println("3 - query list");
        System.out.println("4 - remove from list");
        System.out.println("5 - empty list");
        System.out.println("6 - exit");
        System.out.print("Please choose option: ");

        try
        {
            selectedOption = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            printWrongOperationSelected();
            selectedOption = -1;
        }
    }

    private void printWrongOperationSelected()
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong operation selected.");
    }

    private void processSelectedOption()
    {
        switch (selectedOption)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            {
                addNewElement();
            } break;
            case 3:
            {
                printList();
            } break;
            case 4:
            {
                removeElement();
            } break;
            case 5:
            {
                clearList();
            } break;
            case 6:
            {
                exit();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                printWrongOperationSelected();
            }
        }
    }

    private void addNewElement()
    {
        System.out.print("Please type the number to be added to the list: ");

        Integer newValue = null;
        while(newValue == null)
        {
            try
            {
                newValue = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Wrong value. Please insert new value.");
            }
        }

        MyListElement newElement = new MyListElement(newValue);

        if (firstElement != null)
        {
            placeElementInList(newElement);
        }
        else
        {
            firstElement = newElement;
        }
    }

    private void placeElementInList(final MyListElement newElement)
    {
        if (newElement.value < firstElement.value)
        {
            newElement.nextElement = firstElement;
            firstElement = newElement;
        }
        else
        {
            MyListElement previousElement = firstElement;
            MyListElement elementInList = firstElement.nextElement;
            while (elementInList != null)
            {
                if (newElement.value < elementInList.value)
                {
                    break;
                }
                previousElement = elementInList;
                elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;
            }
            previousElement.nextElement = newElement;
            newElement.nextElement = elementInList;
        }
    }

    private void printList()
    {
        if (firstElement == null)
        {
            System.out.println("No elements in the list.");
        }
        else
        {
            MyListElement elementInList = firstElement;
            while (elementInList != null)
            {
                System.out.print(elementInList.value + ", ");
                elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private void removeElement()
    {
        System.out.print("Please type the number to be removed from the list: ");
        Integer valueToRemove = null;
        while(valueToRemove == null)
        {
            try
            {
                valueToRemove = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Wrong value. Please insert value to remove.");
            }
        }

        if (firstElement == null)
        {
            System.out.println("No elements in the list. None can be removed.");
        }
        else
        {
            boolean found = false;

            if (firstElement.value.equals(valueToRemove))
            {
                firstElement = firstElement.nextElement;
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MyListElement previousElement = firstElement;
                MyListElement elementInList = firstElement.nextElement;
                while (elementInList != null)
                {
                    if (elementInList.value.equals(valueToRemove))
                    {
                        previousElement.nextElement = elementInList.nextElement;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    previousElement = elementInList;
                    elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                System.out.println("Value " + valueToRemove + " is not in the list.");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Value removed.");   
            }
        }
    }

    private void clearList()
    {
        firstElement = null;
    }

    private void exit()
    {
        exitRequested = true;
    }

    private class MyListElement
    {
        private final Integer value;
        private MyListElement nextElement;

        private MyListElement(final Integer value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT(from Phone)**

```
private void printInReverse()
{
    MyListElement tmpElement=firstElement;
    MyListElement previousElement=tmpElement.nextElement;
    while (previousElement!=null)
    {
        previousElement.nextElement=tmpElement;
        tmpElement =previousElement;
        previousElement=previousElenent.nextElement;
    }
    MyListElement firstReverseElement=tmpElement;
    //loop like in the normal print loop but using firstReverseElement as starting point. You can create print methodthat would take First element as param.
}
```

**EDIT - REVERSE ORDER COMPLETE:**

```
private void printList()
{
    printListFromElement(firstElement);
}

private void printListFromElement(final MyListElement firstElementToPrint)
{
    if (firstElementToPrint == null)
    {
        System.out.println("No elements in the list.");
    }
    else
    {
        MyListElement elementInList = firstElementToPrint;
        while (elementInList != null)
        {
            System.out.print(elementInList.value + ", ");
            elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

private void printListInReverse()
{
    if (firstElement == null)
    {
        System.out.println("No elements in the list.");
    }
    else
    {
        MyListElement fistElementInReverse = new MyListElement(firstElement.value);
        MyListElement previousElement;

        MyListElement elementInOriginalList = firstElement;

        while (elementInOriginalList.nextElement != null)
        {
            previousElement = fistElementInReverse;
            fistElementInReverse = new MyListElement(elementInOriginalList.nextElement.value);
            fistElementInReverse.nextElement = previousElement;

            elementInOriginalList = elementInOriginalList.nextElement;
        }
        printListFromElement(fistElementInReverse);
    }
}
```

Here in the reversing loop you have to create new MyListElementObjects. You get infinite loop/break original list/get null pointer if you don't do that, as you only change references in the original list.

Comment: Now everything is clearer to me. I'm glad you thought of breaking the code into methods. I've never practiced that and I know it is a good habit to keep int mind. How could I reverse the elements in the list? Let's say the list contains "1, 2, 3" but I want to print it "3, 2, 1". Should I create another list to insert the numbers or is there a way to sort it backwards (decreasing)? Thank you a lot. @MichalSchielmann

Comment: @user3816423 sorry, im on holidays now, and have only ny phone with me, so producing a code that would compile is not 100% possible;) One way would be to add another field to inner class and that would be called 'previous'. This way you could traverse both ways. I didnt do that because i didnt know if that was allowed. This way you could gobfrom start to finish and back.

Comment: Other way would be to create a loop, possibly in New method. Create New myListElement called lastElement and assign firstElement to that(as in reverse order it's last). Then create newElement=currentElement.nextElement and do newElement.nextElement=currentElement. Tgis way you'll reverse it. Sorry for the poor explanation, but it's all i can do Right now:(

Comment: PS when you're at the end of the loop, call the last element as something like myReverseFirstElement. Having that Object you can go from back(myReverseFirstElement) to beginning(firstElement/reverseLastElement). I hope that It will help:)

Comment: Thank you for the help! But it has to be when it's printing the values. Is there any way to do that? I'm really confused

Comment: @user3816423 can you have previousElement field in your inner class?

Comment: @user3816423 ive edited my answer but i cant check if It compiles/works. I hope It would give to the idea though. Other way is If you can add previousElement to inner class, then do so, and everytime when creating element set its previous element as well as next element in placeElementInList method. Albo save the lastElement as Global instance field. Hope that helps. Cant do nothing more for a week. If this answers your question, to can always accept this answer;)

Comment: Yes I understood what you were trying to do but it gets on an infinite loop (?). Here follows the printinreverse method:
//starting point. You can create print methodthat would take First //element as param.
MyListElement elementInList = firstReverseElement;
while (elementInList != null) {
System.out.print(elementInList.value + ", ");
elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;